# Error after generating Javadoc for my project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

After I generated javadoc for my project on eclipse, the following error messages pop up on the console.
Does anyone has a solution to my problem. I tried to include de modules that are missing in the VM options during the wizards but it still doesn't work.

Thanks

EDIT: I fixed it. First I deleted my module file, then I created the javadoc. After doing that, I configured my module file again and it worked
[screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIn9U.png)

Comment: [Getting “Module javafx.controls not found” error Java Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64560205/10115296) does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake have nothing to do with the Javadoc.
You've got an error because you use JavaFX and you haven't load the dependencies in the classpath.

To resolve your problem :

- Near the run button you have a arrow. Click on it.
- You will have a menu, then click on "run configurations..."
- A pop up will open.
- Then find the name of your main class in the list on the left of the pop up.
- Then go in arguments section
- And in the field named "VM arguments" write :

  --module-path pathToJavaFXJDK/lib --add-modules:javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

replace pathToJavaFXJDK by the absolute path of your JavaFX directory.

Comment: after doing that, he can't find or load main class. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Comment: I fixed it, look at my edit. But thanks anyways!

Comment: Okay perfect. But just remember one thing, the Javadoc CAN'T cause error because it's just comment.