# Java 16 Eclipse issue with JavaFX (java.lang.module.FindException)

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, installation, download

for a uni project i need to make a piechart it's why i decided to use JavaFX, [i follow this tutorial](https://youtu.be/_7OM-cMYWbQ)
I download JavaFX 16, i create my user library, JavaFX16 that i add into Classpath [image: here]

I also add the VM argument "   --module-path "C:\Users\andre\Downloads\openjfx-16_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-16\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml   "
but i still have this error "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found"
[image]

I find [this other stackoverlow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64560205/getting-module-javafx-controls-not-found-error-java-eclipse-ide?answertab=active#tab-top) but it doesn't help. If someone know how to fix this, i would be glad to hear him. (I'm sorry if i made english mistake or that i forgot to add something)

Have a nice day.

Comment: Go to openjfx.io, follow the JavaFX and Eclipse tutorial there. Or install the liberica distribution from bellsoft which includes JavaFX.  Or download Idea community edition and use the new JavaFX project wizard.

Comment: I find a fix, using an other library

Comment: How does such a comment help anybody else with the same problem? You can self answer.